# Question regarding voltage and current

Tags: voltage, current

Please forgive me if this question sounds stupid but I am still an amateur.

I was trying to power a DC motor a while ago and blew a transistor. Later I realized that it was rated for 200mA and I exceeded that with my batteries. 
Anyway then I wondered how to solve this problem. Should I get a transistor that can handle more current or should I step up the voltage (and as I understand decrease the current) so that I don't blow the transistor but still get enough power to the motor (a rather small one). 
I was also wandering if it is a good idea (in general) to step up the voltage and in doing so decease current (correct me if I'm wrong) to protect components that can only handle like 200mA or it it better to get components that can handle more current.

Again I'm a bit nooby so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping up the voltage in order to reduce current only works if the "load" device draws a constant power and this is not the case with a DC motor. If you increase the voltage, the DC motor will spin faster. For instance, if you double the voltage, the rotational speed will approximately double and so will the torque that is delivered to the mechanical load. This means that the power taken quadruples and, the impact of all of this is that the current doubles.

Comment: Thank you! I think in most other situations I would be able to use a npn transistor because there aren't many loads (that I can think of) that use more then 200mA.

Answer (score 0):

The motor is designed for a certain performance at a certain voltage. Applying more voltage to the same motor will not reduce the current, it will increase it (well, up until the point where the motor fails, when it might go up or down).

Motors are a bit of an unusual load compared to something like an LED in that they draw much more current when they are stopped and relatively little when they are spinning with no load (and more again if you put a load on the shaft).

Anyway, if  your motor draws (say) 500mA when running with a load, it might draw considerably more (perhaps several amperes) when starting up. If you "plug" the motor by reversing it while spinning you'll get even more current and may damage the motor.

So your best bet is to use a better transistor. Make sure  you put a diode across the motor (assuming it will only spin in one direction) to absorb any spikes. A MOSFET is often a good choice, but without numbers it's hard to tell what would be best. For example, the [IRLR8726PbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlr8726pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567181dd26f7) is a nice MOSFET in the easy-to-use D-Pack package that can be driven with 5V and costs well under a dollar and can handle many amperes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpcU7d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you I actually have a mosfet but as I understand with the type that I have you have to supply more voltage than the input to switch the mosfet on and I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: The kind I mentioned needs no more than 5V to drive it. You put the load on the drain and ground the source and feed 5V to the gate for on and 0V for off. Very simple. The supply goes to the other side of the motor and can be much higher than 5V, easily 24V for the one I mentioned (with a diode across the motor). Many MOSFETs are designed to work with 10V on the gate so they are much harder to use with a 5V input.